# When I run my code in google colab I am also getting the same error message since 12-4-23

Tags: python-3.x, ta-lib

%%capture
!curl -L http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz -O && tar xzvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
!cd ta-lib && ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make install && cd - && pip install ta-lib

import talib

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

IT seems there is a configuration changes in Google colab in talib environment